# Possible to automatically unlist previous version when deploying a new NuGet package version?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuget-server

Successfully building and publishing my own NuGet packages via a batch script, I would love to automatically [unlist](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package#Deleting_packages) all previous versions when uploading a new version of my package.

What I'm currently doing is to manually use the web browser and unlist the previous versions.

**So my question:**

Is it possible to automatically unlist all previous versions when publishing a new NuGet package version?

Answer (score 1):

If you know the version numbers of the old versions you want to delete/unlist you should be able to script calls to [NuGet delete](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/command-line-reference#Delete_Command).

```
NuGet.exe delete <package Id> <package version> [API Key]
```

Comment: Thanks, Matt, that's what I thought, too. I just wanted to avoid the bookkeeping of remembering the previous version numbers.

Comment: Above example will not unlist the former package version. The package version will still be visible when going to the page of the package at nuget.org

Comment: Mmm, the documentation says it will unlist the package on nuget.org - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/nuget/reference/cli-reference/cli-ref-delete